# repeating a numpy array N times

Tags: python, numpy, repeat

hii experts i have a 1d numpy array and i want to repeat it 3 times vertically,

```
my_input_array = [-1.02295637 -0.60583836 -0.42240581 -0.78376377 -0.85821456]
```

i tried the below code

```
import numpy as np
x=np.loadtxt(my_input_array)
x.concatenate()
```

however i get error...in this way...hope i will get some solution.Thanks.

my expected output should be as below

```
 -1.02295637
 -0.60583836
 -0.42240581
 -0.78376377
 -0.85821456
 -1.02295637
 -0.60583836
 -0.42240581
 -0.78376377
 -0.85821456
 -1.02295637
 -0.60583836
 -0.42240581
 -0.78376377
 -0.85821456
```

Comment: And the error is ?

Comment: concatenation problem...

Comment: That is not the error given by the code

Comment: `x.concatenate()` - where did you get the idea to do this?  It's not a documented method, is it?  You'll have a lot of problems if you make wild guesses without checking documentation.   That said, you might find `np.tile` to be useful - look it up.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: if possible can you please show it...

Comment: np.tile is working but it does not arrange vertically as my expected output

Comment: It's numpy.concatenate, not x.concatenate.

Comment: Please post the actual output of np.tile.

Comment: Don't confuse how something is displayed with what it is.  Look at `x`.  It's a `numpy` array.  Depending on the `shape`, it will display (print) in one line or multiple, with `[]`, and with or without commas.  Look also at how a `list` is display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
x=np.concatenate([my_input_array, my_input_array, my_input_array])
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
-1.02295637
-0.60583836
-0.42240581
-0.78376377
-0.85821456
-1.02295637
-0.60583836
-0.42240581
-0.78376377
-0.85821456
-1.02295637
-0.60583836
-0.42240581
-0.78376377
-0.85821456
```

Comment: but how to arrange the output like my expected result...i donot need array again

Comment: Alternatively,  `np.concatenate([my_input_array]*3)`

Comment: That's the way numpy arrays print by default.  If you need specific formatting, then you have to do the formatting.
`for f in my_array:` 
`    print(f)`

Comment: Of course it does.  You need to provide some of the brains yourself.  I assume you simply typed in my command, without actually creating the array.   `my_array = np.concatenate([my_input_array]*3)`

Answer (score 2):

[`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)

```
np.tile(my_input_array, 3)
```

Output

```
array([-1.02295637, -0.60583836, -0.42240581, -0.78376377, -0.85821456,
       -1.02295637, -0.60583836, -0.42240581, -0.78376377, -0.85821456,
       -1.02295637, -0.60583836, -0.42240581, -0.78376377, -0.85821456])
```

Edit: just noticed @hpaulj's answer. I'll still leave my answer but he mentioned np.tile first.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `tile` method which multiplies the array with given shape and `reshape` method to structure it. Use `x.shape[0]*x.shape[1]` to change it into a column vector without explicitly giving the shape dimensions!

```
x=np.tile(x,(3,1))
y=x.reshape(x.shape[0]*x.shape[1])
```

Comment: i donot need any reshape...it should be automatic without reshaping

Comment: Does it help now?

Comment: glad to help.. I just think you should use this technique as the for loop will only print array but the structure as column vector is really important to manipulate data inside!